# custom windows form properties

Tags: c#

I have created a customize windows form and I just don't know how should I set properties to it.

for example I've created a form with a progress bar, button, and a label and want to set the text of the label, the value of the progress bar, **and to get access to the buttonClick Event method** form the windows form application that uses the control.

In other words just get access to all the default properties of each control inside.

Is it possible? and how should I do it?

thanks very much!

If I want to to get access to the buttonClick Event method how should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to expose controls on a form to outside code.
One way to achieve this would be to declare accessible properties on the form, for example:

```
public ProgressBar MyProgressBar
{
    get { return progressBar1; }
}
```

If you wish to only expose certain properties of the controls, you could also have properties that access these directly, like so:

```
public int MyProgressBarValue
{
    get { return progressBar1.Value; }
    set { progressBar1.Value = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast from `Control` to the type of your custom control before you can access the properties you have defined.

```
var myCtrl = (MyControl)controlRef;
myCtrl.MyProperty = xxxx;
```

This code assumes that `MyProperty` has been declared as `public`.